# Finding Zero with multiple variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have an equation in excel E25/F3+D25-C20

I know the current values of all the variables, but I want to find the value of F3 when the equation is equal to zero. Every variable can change on a daily basis, otherwise I would just brute force this and try variations until I found zero manually.

Example Desired results:

```
4354/15.8+275-551= -0.43          -0.43 needs to be zero, but only change 15.8 to find zero* 

F3=15.775362319 is the correct answer
```

I have tried making it $0=4354/x+275-551$, but I can't seem to get $x$ by itself correctly.

Decimals to the 8th place matter in the answer.

Comment: $E25/(C20-D25) =x$ in case $E25$  is not 0

Comment: Thanks @Maksim !

Comment: Why does the $8^{th}$ decimal matter ? (if not for a homework ?)